# What’s the movie? Alien slime slug monster

Tags: story-identification, horror

When I was really young I saw my father watching some movie and I remember seeing a giant green translucent slug. It was a bright green and looked like slime. I believe it was white at the bottom too. The slug was in some sort of space ship looking setting. I’ve been trying to figure out what movie it was from for a LONG time.  And before anyone says it, it’s not Slugs or Night of the Creeps (and no it wasn’t Star Wars either).

Comment: When was this? No offence, but we don't know when you were young... Was it 10 years ago, 50?

Comment: Some suggestions:
— [The Blob (1958) - IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051418/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2)
— [The Green Slime (1968) - IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064393/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2)
— [The Blob (1988) - IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094761/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

Comment: A long shot, but some similarity with the Third Doctor serial [The Green Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Green_Death)